# sharing code across VS 2010 projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

This may be a stupid question, but is there a nice way for a small team (not using TFS) to easily share code across VS 2010 solutions?

IE, if Project1.DLL is referenced in Project2, then everytime Project1 is republished, the reference in project two will have to be updated.

Am I making any sense?
Thanks!

Comment: That's not code sharing or source control, that's building / compiling. Unless you add the dll as a project to a solution TFS is not nice about it. As far as VS is concerned it's a 3rd party dll, if you want to build everything dependant on it, you have to set up a build script to do it and trigger it as part of project1's build. You could do that in after an build step. Get yourself some source control, lots of free ones about, forgeting to rebuild something is going to be the least of your problems even in a team of one.

Comment: I think you have two questions. 1) How to share code between multiple team members. 2) How to organize the shared code so that one project depends on another project. Correct?

Comment: Thanks, guys, yeah we have Vault source control, the question is just about 2) that you mentioned Morten, how to organize it efficiently so that when the DLL is built the other project references are updated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would organize your repository:

[image]

**Explanation:**

Both Project1 and Project2 should have their own codeline, at the same level.

Project dependencies are handled by branching */Project1/Main* into */Project2/Main/Dependencies/Project1*

Project1 can be consumed by more projects.

Code changes in Project1 must be done in */Project1/Main* and changes must be branched into the projects that needs the changes.

I do not known **Vault**, but I hope it can handle this setup. I have a setup like this using Team Foundation Server 2010.

Comment: @CodyGray, the image is a linux file manager. Just to show the folder structure.

Comment: That is a pretty cool idea, Morten. Thanks so much, I will give this a try.

Comment: @kevin, glad that I could help you. The idea is not mine. It's from a book that had two solutions for your problem. First solution is the one I just described. The second solution is to treat project dependencies as 3rd party binary files. Project1 should check it's binary output into the source control. Then Project2 should then get this binary output, just as the first solution. My favorite is the first solution, since you have the full source and are able to debug.