# TFS 2010 collection folder structure

Tags: tfs

In our current TFS environment, we have 2 collections: let's call them "new" and "old". The old collection is unstructured, there is no branching, it's only being used as a code repository.

The new collection has the following format (we're keeping it as simple as possible):

```
-NewCollection
    -Project Name
        -Dev (branch)
        -Main (branch)
        -Support (branch)
```

Currently only a couple of projects follow this approach (which has been working quite well so far) so we want to move all the remaining projects from the old collection to the new one.

Here is the problem. A lot of our projects in the old collection are WCF services (around 15 or 20 of them) which hold different aspects of our business logic. Our projects have references to these services, and some of these services even reference one another.

Because there are so many services and considering that in the future we want to implement automatic builds and deployments with gated check-ins, etc, what would be wiser to do?

Structure the services like this:

```
-NewCollection
    -Service 1
        -Dev (branch)
        -Main (branch)
        -Support (branch)
    -Service 2
        -Dev (branch)
        -Main (branch)
        -Support (branch)
    -Service 3
        -etc.
```

Or like this:

```
-NewCollection
    -Services
        -Dev (branch)
            -Service 1
            -Service 2
            -Service 3
            -etc.
        -Main (branch)
            -Service 1
            -Service 2
            -Service 3
            -etc.
```

The reason why I'm asking this question is because I don't know what it entails when configuring the builds, etc - I am still learning how to do this and I want to plan the structure of the collection in such a way that it won't complicate our lives when configuring the automatic builds/deployments in the near future.

Comment: Here's an example on how to use a "main-model" for each project and how to handle inter project dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9846068/600559

Comment: Thanks for a useful comment. It's an interesting strategy for dependencies, however we're going to stick to a flat structure because our dependencies sometimes go 3 or 4 levels deep. We have very few .DLL dependencies, and the ones we have we keep in a repository in source control that's just updated manually as and when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use the first structure you mentioned - keep branches under each product. This will simply be a cleaner approach as time goes on.

When you set up a build definition you get to specify branches/workspaces that are part of the GET operation. If you keep your file system layout the same as your source control layout you can simply reference the appropriate service interfaces from each service consumer like you would any other project. Here is an example - in this case I am referencing the Awesomium SDK from my own solution:

[image]

Comment: I went through the options with the other members of the team and we're going for the first option. One of the reasons is to keep it neat, and another because we have services that are larger that might require a different branching strategy in the future than just Dev and Main. So we're trying to keep our options open with regards to the branching as well as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question of branch structure depends on how you plan your releases.

If you find that you almost always release 1 service at a time and the development of the other services are seperate from one another then go for option 1.

If you are more likely to be changing multiple services at the same time and releasing them together then I'd go for option 2.

If you're not sure, or your releases can be mixed then go for option 2. There is no real overhead in having code you don't intend to change in a branch.

If you go for option 1 and you intend to change 2 or 3 services at a time them managing all of the merging between branches is going to be a major overhead.

As for the question about builds, don't worry about it, whatever brahcing strategy you chose, your builds will be OK. However I would say that from expeirience, having all of the solutions / dependancies that you need for a build in a single branch will make life easier in the long run.